# iTextSharp PdfCopy makes read-only fields editable

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm working on some code that concatenates PDF files using iTextSharp. I'm having a problem with [a particular PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nhy7av9b37uwowl/in1.pdf?dl=0) that contains some read-only fields and a field that is editable (I believe they're AcroFields). In the output file all of the fields are editable.

Here is the code that I use (I've simplified it to read only one PDF):

```
public static void Concat(string outputFilePath, string inputFilePath)
{
    using (var document = new Document())
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        using (var copier = new PdfCopy(document, fileStream))
        {
            copier.SetMergeFields();
            document.Open();

            var reader = new PdfReader(inputFilePath);
            copier.AddDocument(reader);
            copier.AddJavaScript(reader.JavaScript);

            copier.Close();
        }
        document.Close();
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to preserve the attributes of the fields?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like iText and Adobe Reader interpret the form field structure differently. E.g. look at this parent field with one child:

[image: PageDataCollection1[0].txtCity]

(Object 24 is referenced from the **AcroForm** dictionary **Fields** array. Object 130 is referenced from the **Page** dictionary **ANNOTS** array.)

So we have two field objects named `PageDataCollection1[0].txtCity`, the objects 24 and 130, the widget annotation being merged into the latter.

*iText* considers the terminal field object (object 130) to be completely in charge, using its **Ff** value `0` which among other things means *not read-only*.

*Adobe Reader*, on the other hand, considers the terminal field object (object 130) only to be partially in charge, using its **DA** value but *not* its **Ff** value. Instead the parent **Ff** value `1` is used which among other things means *read-only*.

In the course of copying the document pages, the hierarchies are flattened making the different interpretation visible.

---

Ad hoc I would say the behavior of iText is correct here.

The behavior of Adobe Reader might be justified with this section from the specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf):

> It is possible for different field dictionaries to have the same fully qualified field name if they are descendants of a common ancestor with that name and have no partial field names (**T** entries) of their own. Such field dictionaries are different representations of the same underlying field; they should differ only in properties that specify their visual appearance. In particular, field dictionaries with the same fully qualified field name shall have the same field type (**FT**), value (**V**), and default value (**DV**).
>
> *(section 12.7.3.2 Field Names)*

Maybe Adobe Reader tries to enforce that different representations of the same field only differ in properties that specify their visual appearance, by ignoring other properties in descendant fields without partial field names.

As there are no different representations of the field, though, there is no need for this measure here.

---

There is an alternative interpretation of the object structure here, @rhens proposed

> There aren't 2 fields with the same name: object 24 is the field dictionary, object 130 is the widget annotation.

IMO this interpretation does not match the PDF specification even though it would explain the behavior of Adobe Reader.

While indeed the **Kids** array of a form field may contain either child fields or widgets, the object 130 in my opinion has to be considered a field (which has *its own widget* merged into itself) rather than a widget of field object 24.

To check whether some kid dictionary object is a child field or merely a widget, it does not suffice to find widget-specific entries in the kid: such entries can also be in a child field which has its single widget merged into itself. Thus, one instead has to check for field-specific entries in the kid.

In the case at hand the kid object 130 *does* have field-specific entries (foremost the field type **FT** but also the field flags **Ff**) and, therefore, should be considered a child *field*.

---

That all been said, it indeed is possible that *Adobe does consider that object a mere widget* (which, as mentioned above, would explain the behavior). This interpretation would not be inspired by the specification, though, as explained above. But it might be inspired by a non-negligible amount of documents from the wild which erroneously have additional field-specific entries in their plain widgets and require this interpretation to be displayed as designed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed analysis! 
Is there a possibility to tell iText to prefer the parent's value for /Ff? 
Or perhaps there is a way to inspect this value and set it manually field by field. 
Or should I rather try a different PDF library?

Comment: *Is there a possibility to tell iText to prefer the parent's value for /Ff?* - As far as I know: No. - *Or perhaps there is a way to inspect this value and set it manually field by field.* - As iText allows you to manipulate PDFs at low level, too, that is no problem. - *Or should I rather try a different PDF library?* - After all that is up to you.

Comment: @mkl You're on the right track with your analysis, but I do think iText is wrong here. There aren't 2 fields with the same name: object 24 is the field dictionary, object 130 is the widget annotation. The PDF spec does not define the Ff entry for annotations. It's only defined for field dictionaries. So it makes sense that Adobe Reader uses the parent's value. I'll edit your answer to reflect this.

Comment: This part of the spec confirms that no overlapping entries are possible for a field dictionary and its associated widget annotation. _"As a convenience, when a field has only a single associated widget annotation, the contents of the field dictionary and the annotation dictionary may be merged into a single dictionary containing entries that pertain to both a field and an annotation. NOTE: This presents no ambiguity, since the contents of the two kinds of dictionaries do not conflict."_

Comment: @bgh We'll fix this in iText.

Comment: @rhens *There aren't 2 fields with the same name: object 24 is the field dictionary, object 130 is the widget annotation.* - I considered that interpretation of the object structure, too, but I doubt it makes sense. Kids of a form field may be widgets or fields. As fields may have merged widgets, you can't decide based on the presence of widget entries but have to look for field entries to decide the nature of a kid. And 130 definitely had field-like entries, so it had to be interpreted as a field

Comment: @mkl Upon second inspection I agree your interpretation is correct according to ISO 32000-1. However, the spec doesn't make a lot of sense here. 12.7.3.2, that you quoted, says such field dicts can only differ in visual appearance. But the parent dict cannot have an associated widget annotation, because it's not a terminal field. As it currently stands, ISO 32000-2 will change and clarify this: a field dict without a partial name (**T** entry) will always be considered a widget annotation. So probably Reader acts according to this common, but currently technically wrong, interpretation.

Comment: @rhens *ISO 32000-2 will change and clarify this: a field dict without a partial name (T entry) will always be considered a widget annotation.* - If Adobe Reader already implements this PDF2 criterion (and it partially already *does* work according to the PDF2 drafts), this would definitely explain the Adobe Reader behavior.

Comment: @bgh Behavior will stay the same in iText, according to current PDF spec.

Comment: @rhens That is okay. I have created, for my specific case, a sub-class of PdfReader which prefers the parent's value for an annotation for each AcroField and that does the trick.